# How to get a 2 column widget area defined in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a page that would hold widget boxes in a 2 column set up. The widget boxes are essentially "boxes" designed in CSS with a different background color that look like boxes. I would later add the appropriate widgets in place.

My CSS skills are not the greatest since I am primarily a backend developer so any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the columns needs to be equal height?

Comment: Yes they would need to be. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/u8qZn/.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using yui3 grids lately for my column layouts, and I'm loving them! Here's a link to a great overview/tutorial: [linky](http://www.goer.org/Journal/2010/10/yui_3_grids_are_dead_simple.html) This is a very easy and flexible solution, which scales well to even very complex layouts.